# Не создаётся массив из индексов

Tags: javascript, массивы, foreach

Здравствуйте! Объясните, пожалуйста, почему не работает данный код?

`var arr = new Array(10).map(function (t, iter) { return iter });
console.log(arr);`

По логике должен получиться массив `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`, но вместо него 10 элементов `undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

> Note: `map()` does not execute the function for array elements without
>   values.

то есть

> `map` не вызывается для элементов массива без значений.

Можете добавить `console.log` внутрь функции параметра `map`, чтобы в этом убедиться.

А вот отсюда https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map :

> Due to the algorithm defined in the specification if the array which
>   `map` was called upon is sparse, resulting array will also be sparse
>   keeping same indices blank.

то есть

> Из-за определения алгоритма данного в спецификации, если исходный массив -
>   разреженный, полученный массив тоже будет разреженным, с пустыми
>   соответствующими элементами.

Answer (score 2):

var arr = new Array(10) создает массив на 10 элементов, которые ПУСТЫЕ.
Что бы заполнить их, можно использовать цикл. Например:

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = i;
}
```

А уже потом Ваш код arr.map(function (t, iter) { return iter });

Comment: Это я понял, но я же вызываю map. Почему он то не работает?